# How to select the first item in array by default?

Tags: react-native

i have a Picker and i have 3 items in an array where i receve tham. I need to put the first item from the array in the picker by default. This is mine picker who receves all items and when i press the dropdown it shows all my drivers but it needs by default to show the first item from the array.

```
       <View style={{width: '50%', paddingRight: 5}}>
          <RNPickerSelect
            style={{
              inputAndroid: styles.dropdownAndroid,
              inputIOS: styles.dropdownIOS,
              placeholder: styles.dropdownPlaceholder,
              iconContainer: styles.dropwownIcon
            }}
            disabled={this.state.vendorDriverSelectDisabled}
            placeholder={{ label: this.props.mainProps.language.selectDriver }}
            onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({...this.state, selectedVendorDriver: value})}
            value={this.state.selectedVendorDriver}
            items={this.state.vendorDrivers}
            useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
            Icon={() => {
              return <EvilIcons name="chevron-down" size={37} color="#333" />
            }}
          />
        </View>
```

Comment: just initialise your `state.selectorVendorDriver` to 0

Comment: when i type this.state.selectVendorDriver[0] i get an error

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant. I meant that in your constructor, you can initialise the state to value `0`, that way in your picker you will have it as the default. Why? Because it's your value. To what do you initialise it right now?

Comment: selectorVendorDriver: null

Comment: that's the issue, change it to 0

Answer (score 1):

When you set data for `vendorDrivers` state, use the code like this?

```
this.setState({ vendorDrivers: someData })
```

So, just set `selectedVendorDriver` state to the first element of the `someData`
And the code will become

```
this.setState({ vendorDrivers: someData, selectedVendorDriver: someData[0] })
```